# How to implement fetch RFC822.SIZE command (without javax.Mail)?

Tags: java, sockets, imap, sslsocketfactory, rfc822

I am now implementing (server / client) based on IMAP2 protocol RFC 1064 through SSL TCP / IP sockets and can not know how to calculate RFC822.SIZE in FETCH command and without using JavaMail API - IMAP Servers.
If possible explanation or way to calculate, thanks.

Comment: What are your messages?  Are they files?

Comment: Im export my email messages in (.pst) file format

Comment: RFC 1064? Really? Most people find 3501 preferable. I don't think anyone here will be able to help you with 1064, that really is obsolete.

Comment: The questions  how to calculate the rfc822.size !! In rfc 1064 and rfc 3501 the fetch command will return the rfc822.size

Comment: RFC822.SIZE is just the number of bytes in the message

Comment: As @user253751 says, calculate what you would send for the RFC822 item (which is just the entire message, headers and all), and take the byte length of that.  No parsing required.